# How to handle "No suitable driver found" exception while connecting MySQL with Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am using Eclipse LUNA package and MySQL 6.0 Workbench.

I pasted "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" file in Referenced Library file.

My coding:

```java
package a1;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
class a2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection dbCon = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "select * from k111";
    try {
      dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
      stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      System.out.println("Success");
      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(query);
      }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      dbCon.close();
    }
  }
}
```

My database name is "test". My table name is k111.

I need to print "Success" as per the program to know whether the database connectivity is successful.

My output:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jdbc URL might be wrong try something like that:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
```

Supply url to your mysql folder

Comment: This is also not working...... Also, my database name is "test" .... So only I put test in that place..... May I know the reason to change it to "mysql"....????

Comment: Oh sorry haha you might take a look on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Comment: ok..... when I add "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");" in my code, I got cleared that exception........ Thanks for your kind response

Comment: Sorry for my mistake :)